# Neo4j check if node exists before creating?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a feeling I'm going about this all wrong. But anyway.

I have an sql database which has essentially a purposefully denormalised table which I've constructed to make this task easier for me, so I can just grab stuff from one table.

What I have is a table of pairs, something like this:

```
user_lo | user_hi | something_else | other stuff
1000    | 1234    | 1231251654     | 123
1050    | 1100    | 1564654        | 45648
1080    | 1234    | 456444894648   | 1
```

And so on.

So for my neo4j graph db, I want each user id as a node, the other stuff isn't too important but will be the stuff in the relations basically.

I only want one node for each user, so my feeling is that if I do something like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    node_lo = db.createNode();
    node_lo.setProperty("user_id", rs.getInt(1));
    node_hi = db.createNode();
    node_hi.setProperty("user_id", rs.getInt(2));
}
```

That when we add the node with user_id 1234 for the second time, it will just create a new node, but I what I want is for it to just grab this node instead of creating it so I can add it to the relationship to 1080 in this case.

So what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [CREATE UNIQUE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create-unique.html)?

If you can't use Cypher, maybe you can use [unique nodes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/transactions-unique-nodes.html#transactions-get-or-create)?

Comment: Yes, this absolutely works, for example if you use merge(n:State {name:"LoadAd"});
it will only create the node if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

Use an index to search, and if no result of found, create a new one.

```
Index<Node> userIndex = graphDatabaseService.index().forNodes('UserNodes');

IndexHits<Node> userNodes = userIndex.get('id', 1234);

if(!userNodes.hasNext()){
    //Create new User node
} else {
    Node userNode = userNodes.next();
}
```

Is this the type of operation you are looking for?

Comment: That could work. Is this faster or slower or the same as the get or ccreate method linked to by Andres? It's look like they kind of do the same thing in different ways, but I don't really understand how indexes work in neo4j yet.

Comment: I would imagine that indexing would be faster, as indexing is usually meant for fast lookup.

Comment: I don't know if I'm reading the docs wrong, but doesn't get or create use an index anyway? I'm confused.

Comment: It indexes the Node or Relationship ID, but everything else you'll need to create your own index for anything else you want indexed.

Comment: Doesn't work, I included a SSCCE at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255542/neo4j-graph-index-fornodes-not-finding-nodes

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use the [UniqueNodeFactory](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/transactions-unique-nodes.html#transactions-get-or-create) provided by Neo4j.

```
    public Node getOrCreateUserWithUniqueFactory( String username, GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
{
    UniqueFactory<Node> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory( graphDb, "UserNodes" )
    {
        @Override
        protected void initialize( Node created, Map<String, Object> properties )
        {
            created.setProperty( "id", properties.get( "id" ) );
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate( "id", id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your SQL tables to look like nodes and relationships.  Then with cypher in your migration you can make the migration rerunnable by something like

```
start a = node:node_auto_index('id:"<PK_Value>"')
delete a

create a = {id: "<PK_VALUE>", etc}
```

for nodes and since you should have in your many-to-many middle table:

```
start LHS = node:node_auto_index('id:"<LHS_PK>"'),
      RHS = node:node_auto_index('id:"<RHS_PK>"')
create unique LHS=[:<relType> {<rel props>}]->RHS
```

now you will end up with no duplicates and can rerun as much as you like.

Answer (score 1):

use this function:
where:
ID is the key which you want to check if already exist
Type: is the type of the node ( the label)
this function will create the node and return it, then you can add more properties.

```
public static Node getOrCreateUserWithUniqueFactory( long ID, GraphDatabaseService graphDb, String Type )
{
    UniqueFactory<Node> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory( graphDb, Type )
    {
        @Override
        protected void initialize( Node created, Map<String, Object> properties )
        {

            created.addLabel( DynamicLabel.label( Type ) );
            created.setProperty( "ID", properties.get( "ID" ) );
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate( "ID", ID );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using cypher query, you can create a unique node with the following syntax,

```
CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:node_auto_index{id:1})
```

when making a REST call, one can make batch insertion like

```
$lsNodes[] = array(

            'method'=> 'POST', 'to'=> '/cypher',

            'body' => array(
                'query' => 'CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:node_auto_index{id_item:{id}})',
                'params'    =>  array('id'=>1)
            ),
            'id'=>0

        );

        $sData = json_encode($lsNodes);
```

similarly for creating relationships in a batch request, do the following

```
$lsNodes[] = array(

                        'method'=> 'POST', 'to'=> '/cypher',

                        'body'  => array(
                            'query'     => 'start a=node:node_auto_index(id={id1}), b = node:node_auto_index(id={id2}) create unique a-[:have{property:30}}]-b;',
                            'params'    => array(
                                'id1'  => 1, 'id2'=>  2
                            )
                        ),
                        'id'    => 0

                    );
$sData = json_encode($lsNodes);
```