# Neo4j GraphQL how to check if node exists before connecting to it

Tags: neo4j, graphql

B"H

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999730/neo4j-check-if-node-exists-before-creating) and I want to do the same thing with the [GraphQL driver for Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/). I think the answer lies somewhere in combining AND and OR operators found [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/filtering/), of some sort, but not sure how.

To illustrate the question, say I have this type:

```
type Comment  {
    id: ID @id
    timeAdded: DateTime! @timestamp(
        operations: [CREATE]
    )
    writer: User! @relationship(
        type: "WRITTEN_BY",
        direction: IN
    )
    content: String
}

type User {
   id: ID @id
   name: String
   commentsWritten: [Comment!]! @relationship(
        type: "WRITTEN_BY",
        direction: OUT
    )
}

type Mutation {
    addComment(authorID: String)
}
```

and this resolver to add a new comment (where "Comment" is a reference to the OGM model of the Comment type):

```
addComment: async (
        src,
        args,
        ctx
    ) => {

        var authorID = args/*edit*/.authorID //let's say this is passed
                 //from request headers / JWT token or something

        var adCom = await Comment.create({
            input: [
                {
                    content: args.content,
                    writer: {
                        connect: {
                            where: {
                                node: {
                                    users: {
                                        id: authorID
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        })

        return adCom;
    }
```

So it attempts to connect to that user with that ID. but if there is no user with that ID, I don't want to create anything [not only do I not want to connect it].

I could run another query to find a User with that ID, and test if it went through, but was wondering if it's possible to do everything in one call

Comment: Not sure about the Neo4J aspects of this Q but from a GraphQL pov it might be best to validate that you have a real user in your `context` function before allowing a non-existent userId through to your resolvers. What I normally do in `context` is validate the JWT and extract the user's id from it, then lookup the user and add the entire user object to the context.

Comment: @MichelFloyd based on the schema I would say it's just typo and that he meant to extract the authorID from the args parameter